# PlayFramework 2 with Jackson JsonViews annotating methods

Tags: playframework-2.0, jackson

I am trying to define some Views of an entity to translate it to json in some different ways. In Jax-rs is possible to annotate the REST resource method also with @JsonView to specify which view you want in each resource. Is it possible to do something similar with Controller methods in PlayFramework 2?

My Entity:

```
public class User {
    public static class Normal{};
    public static class Complete extends Normal{};

    @Id
    @JsonView(Complete.class)
    private ObjectId id;
    @JsonView(Normal.class)
    @Property("user")
    private String username;
    @Property("pass")
    @JsonView(Normal.class)
    private String password;
    ...
}
```

And a Controller method like this:

```
@JsonView(User.Normal.class)
public static Result getUsers(){
    List<User> users = User.findAll();
    return ok(Json.toJson(users));
}
```

I want it to return only the fields annotated with @JsonView(Normal.class) and obviously this isn't working, it returns also the id field. Is it possible to get it without having to use manually ObjectMapper?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be interested in using that functionality as well, have you found an answer for this on your own?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer so I made a simple static method to return a json with a desired view using ObjectMapper.

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of making a plugin for play framework or contribute to it (since it is a OS project). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... it is working for me.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

    try {
        String ret = mapper.writerWithView(User.Normal.class)
                .writeValueAsString(User.findAll());
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. That's what I was referring by using the ObjectMapper manually

Comment: As far as i know..only manually way..  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews